# Mongoose update document array subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this schema containing an array of subSchemas like this:

```
var timesheetSchema = mongoose.model('Timesheet', new Schema({
  _owner: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
  },
  name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
  },
  members: [memberSchema],
  slots: [slotSchema]
}), 'Timesheet');
```

**Slot schema (bit long sorry)**

```
var slotSchema = mongoose.model('Slot', new Schema({
  _email: {
    required: true,
    type: String
  },
  description: {
    required: false,
    type: String
  },
  date: {
    required: true,
    type: Date
  },
  from: {
    required: true,
    type: Date
  },
  to: {
    required: true,
    type: Date
  }
}), 'Slot');
```

Trying to push an new slot into the `slots[]` but this doesn't seems to work!

```
var query = Timesheet.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { '_id': timesheetId },
    { '$push': { 'slots': newSlot }}
);

query.exec(function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return next(error);
    }

    return res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

**Error**

```
 [CastError: Cast to undefined failed for value "[object Object]" at path "slots"]
  message: 'Cast to undefined failed for value "[object Object]" at path "slots"',
  name: 'CastError',
  kind: undefined,
```

It says slots is undefined but the timesheet does have the `slots[]`!
[image]

**Some checking**

```
 console.log('Timesheet:' + timesheet);
 console.log('NewSlot:' + newSlot);        
 console.log('Timesheets slots: ' + timesheet.slots);
```

**Result**

```
Timesheet:{ 
  members: [],
  slots: [],
  __v: 0,
  name: '2211221',
  _owner: 570babdcbc431d20afeea445,
  _id: 570d14f90482bf5d15a895e2 }
NewSlot:{ 
  _id: 570d18beb3d3c57715b4ee75,
  to: Tue Apr 12 2016 16:36:09 GMT+0200 (CEST),
  from: Tue Apr 12 2016 16:36:09 GMT+0200 (CEST),
  date: Tue Apr 12 2016 16:36:09 GMT+0200 (CEST),
  description: 'WEINIG',
  _email: 'test1' }
Timesheets slots: undefined
```

If there is more information needed I will update my question as soon as possible!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post schema of memberSchema

Comment: It's not about the memberSchema but slotSchema, I could post this if that helps

Comment: Yeah please post `slotSchema`.

Comment: Ah sorry,  my mistake. Please post slotSchema.

Comment: Slot schema is added

Comment: Your slot schema is not a schema, it's a model. Not sure, but I think you need to give Mongoose a `new Schema()` instead of `mongoose.model()`.

All arrays are automatically created by mongoose, so you do have `slots[]`, but it's empty since it doesn't know what to put in there and how to map the object that you have given it into a valid mongoose schema.
You can actually try this by replacing the `slotSchema` with the copy/paste of the slot schema directly, see if it works.

Otherwise you can simply pass slotSchema._id there, like `slots: [{slotId: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'slots'}]`.

Comment: Then later you can populate stuff on request. But the way you have it defined would save the slot in the slots db, and also since you add a full schema (or it seems like you're trying), another slot in the timesheet.slots[].

Comment: @Zlatko thanks for your response, I figured out that by using it directly in the schema it works just fine, which seems a bit strange to me!